# Can I chose to bring a shockland untapped into play when I tutor it with an effect that brings a land tapped into play

Tags: magic-the-gathering

One of my [Flagstones of Trokair](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlagstones%20of%20Trokair%5d) is dying and I search for an [Godless Shrine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGodless%20Shrine%5d). Does the Godless Shrine enters play untapped when I pay the 2 life?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would come into play tapped as a ruling on the card says other abilities take precedence. If you look at [the Gathering page for Godless Shrine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=96935) you will find your answer.

> If another effect (such as Loxodon Gatekeeper’s ability) tells you to put lands onto the battlefield tapped, it enters the battlefield tapped whether you pay 2 life or not.

Comment: Wow so you have the choice to pay 2 life if you want to?

Comment: @corsiKa Yes you do. It is rarely useful though.

Comment: Yes,  many a misclick made you take 2 damage for no reason back when Farseek and Shocks were in standard together

Answer (score 15):

No.

If you read [Godless Shrine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGodless%20Shrine%5d)'s ability carefully, you'll notice that it doesn't say the card enters the battlefield untapped if you do pay; it says the card enters the battlefield tapped if you don't pay.

Godless Shrine only affects how the card comes into the battlefield when you don't pay; it doesn't affect how the card comes into the battlefield when you do pay.

[Flagstones of Trokair](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlagstones%20of%20Trokair%5d) causes Godless Shrine to come into play tapped, and Godless Shrine doesn't do anything about that (even if you do pay).